# Using the Axis 214 PTZ camera in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I want to use the Axis 214 PTZ camera with ROS and have found this Driver:

[axis](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=axis_camera)

After downloading this package I've seen that this package only consists of two files:

*axis.ph;
manifest.xml*

So I have create my own package with the dependencies written in the manifest and  included the *axis.ph* file. After building the package I started the node but nothing happened (node is not running, no erros). Is that the right method? I'm a total newbie in ROS and Ubuntu. Therefore it would be nice if someone could give me a brief instruction. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45682/using-the-axis-214-ptz-camera-in-ros/) by [platzhirsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3129/platzhirsch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try [ours](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/axis_camera). It was based on the one you found, but the one you found is somewhat deprecated.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4